# What is the correct way to override DOM event handlers?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

If I have created a button and attached a click handler:

```
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Do Something";
btn.onclick = () => { doSomething(); };
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

And later I want to re-use the button for something else, is this a safe way to override the event handler?

```
btn.innerHTML = "Do Something Else";
btn.onclick = () => { doSomethingElse(); }
```

I've seen some examples that set `btn.onclick = null;` before attaching a new handler. Also some examples with `addEventListener()` / `removeEventListener()`. Is there a difference between these methods? Can I be introducing memory leaks with any of these?

Comment: it should be fine if you override the listener callback, probably they would be setting it to null or removing it to disable the event associated with the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow multiple handlers to be installed for the same event on a given object, you can call its `addEventListener()` method, which manages a list of handlers for the given event on the object. A handler can then be removed from the object by calling its `removeEventListener()` function.

After removing the previous event handler, you can again attach a new `event` handler to the same element. This way there wouldn't be any memory leaks as well.

**Code Demo:**

```
let btn = document.createElement("button");
btn.innerHTML = "Do Something";
element.addEventListener("click", doSomething, true)
document.body.appendChild(btn);

           ...
btn.removeEventListener("click", doSomething, true);
```

// Third argument  must be same as in earlier case. true in this case.

```
btn.addEventListener("click",doSomethingThingElse};
```

Comment: Thank you! Does `btn.onclick = ...` cause a memory leak?

Comment: Personally I feel, It will be causing. As our handler remains there and just the reference is set to null. But I am not 100% Sure  Mate :) If my answer has helped you by any way. Do Vote and accept the answer for other developers to benefit from :) Thank u

Comment: Upvoted for your help, but it's still not fully clear to me. The old handler is not referenced anymore, so it should be garbage-collected. No?

Comment: Ya! But we do not control Garbage Collection ourselves. It is an automatic process. That's what Memory Leaks are in fact. Garbage collection may or may not happen immediately. :)

Comment: Oh I'm OK with some delay. I just want to make sure I'm not creating things that stay in memory indefinitely. Good point tho.

Comment: Release when the memory is not needed anymore:                                         
The majority of memory management issues occur at this phase. The most difficult aspect of this stage is determining when the allocated memory is no longer needed. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: In the above comment, I am sharing you some valuable information :) About Memory Leaks Issue :) And why we are not sure when will Garbage Collection start to act. Just Click on the Link and get more knowledge ! God Bless